# What would be the hazard of raising flaps on the ground?

Tags: ground-operations

I was reading ASRS report when I found something I don’t understand. What would be the hazard of raising flaps on the ground? What bad thing can happen?

> However, with all the activity around the aircraft, including refueling, it was not safe to raise the flaps. I elected…not to raise the flaps until the area cleared.

https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/callback/cb_482.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without knowing what type of aircraft was involved in this incident, it is hard to tell. But, in general, a moving flap would provide a pinch point for any personnel in the area. Considering the article mentions that the hydraulics were in the on position, there would be a possibility of crushing a body part of maintenance personnel.

Answer (score 11):

Later on, the same ASRS report says

> the refueling truck struck a flap fairing when departing

Thus, the deployed flaps were low enough that raising them would risk hitting someone or something.

---

We may not be able to learn the aircraft's type, because

> ASRS’s award winning publication CALLBACK is a monthly safety newsletter, which includes *de-identified* ASRS report excerpts with supporting commentary in a popular “lessons learned” format.

Comment: If they include the date (even the rough date) of the incident, searching avhearld or the FAA site in that time frame should turn up the actual incident in question. Other details of the event could be used if a date isn't provided. It may not be easy, but it could likely be done.

Comment: @FreeMan, this incident wouldn't be on AVHerald: it involves a parked aircraft and no danger to passengers.

Comment: There's got to be documentation on it somewhere, @Mark. I was just pointing out that even though CALLBACK doesn't give the specific info, there may be enough clues available to track down the specific incident if someone _really_ wanted to know. Not suggesting it will be easy, just that it's probably possible.